# Measurement units after numbers - genitive plural or nominative singular?

Tags: числительные, существительные, падежи

If a number ends with 0,5,6,7,8, or 9, the following noun is used in genitive plural. Do measurement units make an exception or not?

Compare:

1. В стаде триста девяносто коров. (<strike>В стаде тристо девяносто корова.</strike>)
2. Файл весит триста девяносто мегабайт/мегабайтов.

So, which one is correct in the second sentence? Strangely, in case of length measurements, such as километров, метров, миль it is obvious that only genitive plural is acceptable, and not the nominative. However in case of байт, грамм, ватт, etc, I can't figure out which version is more correct.

In case of numbers ending with 1, 2, 3, and 4, there seems to be no discrepancy, because all the measurement units seem to follow the regular pattern (nominative singular for 1, genitive singular for 2,3,4).

> Файл весит двадцать четыре мегабайта. (obviously never <s>двадцать четыре мегабайт</s>)

Comment: "Ending with 1, 2, 3 and 4" rule isn't correct. For numbers ending on 11-20, word has the same form as for 0-9. http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/l10n/pluralforms#r

Comment: @kirilloid: That doesn't mean the rule isn't correct, it means that it has an exception :) Anyway, I didn't want to complicate the question by going into too much unnecessary detail

Comment: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/418/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-vs-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2-a-new-case-or-two-different-words-with-separate-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some unit names form an exception:

> Ряд существительных мужского первого склонения отступает от закономерности «нулевая флексия в им. п. ед. ч. — ненулевая флексия в род. п. мн. ч.» и образует форму род. п. мн. ч. с нулевой флексией. К ним относятся и названия мер и единиц измерения: ампер, ватт, вольт, герц, грамм, килограмм, гектар, рентген, эрг.

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1194-1215.html

http://www.traktat.com/language/book/sush/sks.php

Unitwise (gramota.ru):

> ВАТТ, -а; мн. род. ватт; м. [англ. watt]. Лампочка в сто ватт.
>
> БАЙТ, -а; р. мн. байтов, **счётн.ф.** байт
>
> ГЕКТАР, -а; мн. род. гектаров, (**при счёте**) гектар; м. [франц. hectare]

Comment: Does this imply that saying: Файл весит 300 мегабайтов is incorrect and the only correct form is Файл весит 300 мегабайт?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Yes, it does.