# "нет грамм" vs. "нет граммов": a new case or two different words with separate paradigms?

Tags: падежи

The question comes from the discussion [here](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/409/185) and is a little bit geeky =)

It was suggested that there may be a new case in Russian: Счетный (Numerative).

As an instance of this case, [Anixx](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users/194/anixx) gave the following example:

> на этой шкале нет граммов (Genitive)
>
> пуля весит девять грамм (Numerative)

However, it seems to me that the word "грамм" is two different lexemes with different paradigms. These words mean different things in the examples above: one is a unit of weight and the other one is a mark on a scale. It is two different words, but both are in Genitive case.

First word: "грамм" - a unit of weight, Genitive: "грамм" (Alternative "граммов" is also possible, but in my opinion "грамм" sounds better).

Second word: "грамм" - a mark on a scale, Genitive: "граммов" ("грамм" is not acceptable).

Question: do you think that there is such case as Numerative? If yes, give more examples, if no, do you think that the separation of the word "грамм" on two lexemes is justified?

Comment: In the chat you asked about the example "описание годов учебы, послевоенных лет." I suggest to compare it with "получение граммов основной дозы, дополнительных грамм". It seems these are different semantical cases because the forms are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This proposed case has distinct forms for many measure units:

```
Genitive               Numerative

не хватает годов       пять лет   
не хватает людей       пять человек   
не хватает вольтов     пять вольт   
не хватает амперов     пять ампер   
не хватает граммов     пять грамм   
не хватает битов       пять бит   
не хватает байтов      пять байт   
не хватает каратов     пять карат   
не хватает эргов       пять эрг   
не хватает гауссов     пять гаусс   
не хватает радианов    пять радиан   
не хватает кельвинов   пять кельвин   
не хватает стерадианов пять стерадиан   
не хватает мегагерцев  пять мегагерц   
не хватает ангстремов  пять ангстрем   
не хватает микронов    пять микрон   
не хватает децибелов   пять децибел   
не хватает гранов      пять гран   
не хватает рентгенов   пять рентген   
не хватает бэров       пять бэр   
не хватает разов       пять раз
не хватает аршинов     пять аршин
не хватает ваттов      пять ватт
не хватает гектаров    пять гектар
```

Also many other nouns have distinct forms, such as names of soldiers:

```
Genitive        Numerative
нет драгун      пять драгунов
нет гусар       пять гусаров
нет улан        пять уланов        
нет кирасир     пять кирасиров     
нет сарацин     пять сарацинов
нет гренадёр    пять гренадёров
нет кадет       пять кадетов
нет гардемарин  пять гардемаринов
```

And things that occur in pairs:

```
Genitive       Numerative
нет сапог      пять сапогов
нет чулок      пять чулков
нет валенок    пять валенков
нет носок      пять носков
нет бот        пять ботов
нет рельс      пять рельсов
нет погон      пять погонов
нет манжет     пять манжетов
нет эполет     пять эполетов
```

Vegetables:

```
Genitive               Numerative
не хватает баклажан    пять баклажанов
не хватает помидор     пять помидоров 
не хватает патиссон    пять патиссонов
```

Comment: Why do you think the forms are opposed? They are either equally used or just wrong (*носок, чулков, сапогов*, all military terms with `-ов` and vegetables with null postfixes)

Comment: What is wrong as you claim? баклажан, баклажанов: http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morph.cgi?flags=wndnnnnp&root=config&word=%E1%E0%EA%EB%E0%E6%E0%ED гусар, гусаров: http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/morph.cgi?flags=wndnnnnp&root=config&word=%E3%F3%F1%E0%F0 They listed as forms of genitive but usedd differently.

Comment: You are right, recent editions list both forms for vegetables (though Rosenthal lists *баклажанов* as the only acceptable form). As for "used differently", please source your claim.

Comment: You gave here many examples, but I find some of the forms interchangeable plus some of the interchangeable forms are considered wrong (although they are widespread). I think it would be easier to discuss these examples in a chat. I've crated a [room dedicated to less known cases](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3939/less-known-russian-cases).

Answer (score 3):

Zaliznyak in *О понимании термина "падеж"* argues that semantics of the declined noun should never be taken into account when defining cases.

> Покажем эту связь на примере. Если при описании русского языка принята классическая 6-падежная схема (и, следовательно, например, у номинатемы *сад* в клетке предложного падежа находятся сегменты сад и саду), то невозможно дать никаких стандартных правил управления, в частности, для ситуации S1, (контекст «говорить о...»; семантическая роль «предмет разговора») или ситуации S2, (контекст «находиться в...»; семантическаи роль «место, где нечто находится»). В самом деле, нельзя сказать *говорить о саду* или *находиться в виде*. Это значит, что ситуации S1 и S2, совместимые с номинатемой *сад*, не допускают для нее предложного падежа (поскольку каждая из них допускает лишь один сегмент из соответствующей клетки). S1 и S2 не допускают для номинатемы *сад* также никакого другого падежа. Следовательно, никакие стандартные правила управления для этих ситуаций невозможны. Если же признать существование двух предложных падежей, то для S1 и S2, становятся возможными простые правила управления: S1 всегда допускает обычный (1-й) предложный падеж; S2 всегда допускает 2-й предложный падеж.

There are also other measure units with a null postfix in what here is called numerative: *ампер, вольт, моль, ангстрем, ренгтен*.

Introducing a separate lexeme for each of them in a sense "applied unit vs. abstract unit" (and not doing the same for, say, *литр* or *метр*) would be too far on the wrong side of Occam's razor.

Comment: This question is different from what Zaliznyak argues about. He tells that two cases should not be different just because their semantics is different. I'm telling that it is not two different cases, but two different words.

Comment: I guess then it is the matter of taste: would you rather have several lexemes with identical paradigms or one more cell in the paradigm that the vast majority of words fill with the ending of Genitive case. What part do you want to shave off with Occam's razor? =)

Comment: @Olga: morphological analysis is not a "matter of taste", it's quite an exact science. How would you define this separate lexeme (say, for *вольтов*) in a dictionary?

Comment: Of course, morphological analysis is an exact science. It should be performed with respect to a set of established guidelines, but when establishing the guidelines we often take opposite opinions. Maybe one of the reasons for this is that the formalism we use does not rely on clearly defined concepts, or the definitions are cyclic. I do not know how to define this separate "грамм" lexeme, it needs some research. Based on the examples above, I would define it as a "mark on the scale of a measuring instrument". If there are more examples, the definition has to be adjusted.

Comment: @Olga: I believe *грамм* just hasn't stabilized its pl. gen. yet. You can say both *девять грамм(ов) в сердце* and *шкала килограмм(ов)*.

Comment: Se my answer below.

Comment: @Quassnoi it is always шкала килограммов.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be assuming that singular and plural are the only [grammatical numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number). This assumptions isn't true for most Slavic languages, in particularly it isn't true for Russian.

## When you are counting things..

..then the rules are way more complicated, e.g. there is [Dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_%28grammatical_number%29):

```
  два   грамма
  двух  грамм
  двум  граммам
  два   грамма
  двумя граммами
о двух  граммах
```

If you look closely, this declination doesn't match either the singular or the plural declination of the word `грамм`. As you noticed, some words also have a special [numeral form](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) for numbers other than 2, 3, 4 and it also has its own declination rules:

```
  девять  грамм
  девяти  граммов
  девяти  граммам
  девять  грамм
  девятью граммами
о девяти  граммах
```

This declination mostly matches plural with the exception of Nominative and Accusative.

## To sum up

There is only one word but grammatical numbers other than singular and plural make declination more complicated than what you learn in school.

Comment: Hi, the case with what is the old dual form (два грамма, три грамма, четыре грамма) is covered under the other Numerative case [in this post](http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/405/185), which is very regular and against which I'm not arguing. The rest of the declension can be described in terms of the classic 6 cases.