# Why is "зуб" in genitive case in the following comparison?

Tags: грамматика, родительный-падеж

I couldn't understand why "`зуб`" is in genitive case(`зубов`) in the following sentence. What is the grammatical explanation for that?

> у меня в два раза больше зубов,чем у тебя.

Comment: Not  exactly a duplicate as this is  different case (pun not intended), but check this discussion: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/418/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-vs-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2-a-new-case-or-two-different-words-with-separate-p

Comment: Why "a lot" uses Genitive in English?

Answer (score 6):

The explanation is very simple - you must use genitive after *больше* and *меньше* as well as after *много* and *мало* or telling an exact number (*у меня десять пальцев и сто тысяч волос*).

Comment: unless the last digit of the number is in 1-4 range and the second to last digit is not 1.

Answer (score 1):

"*more teeth*" and "*less teeth*" in Russian is like in English "*number **of** teeth*" using **of**. Like if in English you would say "*more of teeth*".
And word **of** indicates that the next word is in genitive case.

Answer (score 0):

Words which describe inexact quality govern genitive plural: много котов, мало котов, больше котов, чем у тебя, немного котов, несколько котов, столько же котов, сколько у вас котов...

Words which describe number also govern genitive plural unless then end by 1,2,3,4, but not 11,12,13,14: 8 котов, 112 котов.

However, quantors есть коты, некоторые коты, все коты govern nominative plural.

Comment: нет котов  but contextually нет кота, if cat supposed to be singular :P